# (Python) multiple counters in a for loop?

Tags: python

trying to have multiple counters, where if you get a question right or wrong, it's respective counter will go up by one.

The code is janky and not really the simplest way to do certain things (I think), as I'm new to coding.

```
import random
wordBank=["throw"]
word=random.choice(wordBank)
letters=list(word)

print("Welcome to Hangman!")
print()

for i in range(5):
  rightGuess=0
  wrongGuess=0
  print(wrongGuess,"/ 10 Wrong Guesses Used")
  answer=input("Choose a letter: ")
  if answer in letters:
    print("There's a",answer,"!")
    rightGuess+=1
  else:
    print("There's no",answer,"!")
    wrongGuess+=1
```

Here's my entire code. I want the wrongGuess counter to go up by 1 every time the user incorrectly guesses, and the rightGuess counter to go up by 1 whenever the user correctly answers, but it's not doing that.

Comment: the wordBank will have more words in it later, I just have one word in it for testing.

Comment: The loop should not initialize the counters, only *increment* them.

Comment: Using a debugger would have made the problem obvious.

Comment: Style suggestion: f-strings. `print("There's no",answer,"!")` => `print(f"There's no {answer}!")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now you reset the counter every pass of the cycle,
I think you wanted the counter not to reset.
If I understood you correctly then this is the solution:

````
wordBank=["throw"]
word=random.choice(wordBank)
letters=list(word)

print("Welcome to Hangman!")
print()

rightGuess=0
wrongGuess=0

for i in range(5):
  print(wrongGuess,"/ 10 Wrong Guesses Used")

  answer=input("Choose a letter: ")
  
  if answer in letters:
    print("There's a",answer,"!")
    rightGuess+=1

  else:
    print("There's no",answer,"!")
    wrongGuess+=1```
````

Comment: Can't believe I didn't see that before! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Slight modification to your code, rightGuess, wrongGuess initializations to 0 should be outside the for loop.

```
import random
wordBank=["throw"]
word=random.choice(wordBank)
letters=list(word)

print("Welcome to Hangman!\n")
rightGuess=0
wrongGuess=0
for i in range(5):
    print(wrongGuess,"/ 10 Wrong Guesses Used")
    answer=input("Choose a letter: ")
    if answer in letters:
        print("There's a",answer,"!")
        rightGuess+=1
    else:
        print("There's no",answer,"!")
        wrongGuess+=1
```